# DynamicException : invalidPropertyName with org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntity

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

So i was trying to use dynamicJaxb to read xml files without generating jaxbEntities.
I got an exception when trying to read **USPrice** parameter. After debugging the DynamicEntity object, i found that the property name was **usPrice**.

Below the output:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@3f6f6701
Exception in thread "main"      shipTo : {USAddress}
        {
            name/text() : Alice Smith
            street/text() : 123 Maple Street
            city/text() : Mill Valley
            state/text() : CA
            zip/text() : 90952
        }
        billTo : {USAddress}
        {
            name/text() : Robert Smith
            street/text() : 8 Oak Avenue
            city/text() : Old Town
            state/text() : PA
            zip/text() : 95819
        }
        comment/text() : Hurry, my lawn is going wild!
        items : {Items}
        {
            item : [{Item}, {Item}]
            {
            {
                    productName/text() : Lawnmower
                    quantity/text() : 1
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-51000] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DynamicException
Exception Description: Invalid DynamicEntity[DynamicEntityType(Item) - XMLDescriptor(org.tempuri.po.Items.Item --> [])] property name: USPrice
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DynamicException.invalidPropertyName(DynamicException.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntityImpl.get(DynamicEntityImpl.java:169)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteDynamicEntity(TestJAxbGeneration.java:60)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteObject(TestJAxbGeneration.java:76)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteObject(TestJAxbGeneration.java:81)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteDynamicEntity(TestJAxbGeneration.java:67)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteObject(TestJAxbGeneration.java:76)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteDynamicEntity(TestJAxbGeneration.java:67)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteObject(TestJAxbGeneration.java:76)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.traiteObject(TestJAxbGeneration.java:89)
    at com.zahmoul.TestJAxbGeneration.main(TestJAxbGeneration.java:42)
```

the Xsd file :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
   Purchase order schema for Example.com.
   Copyright 2000 Example.com. All rights reserved.
  </xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>

 <xs:element name="purchaseOrder" type="PurchaseOrderType"/>

 <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string"/>

 <xs:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="shipTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element ref="comment" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="items"  type="Items"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="orderDate" type="xs:date"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="USAddress">
      <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
       Purchase order schema for Example.Microsoft.com.
       Copyright 2001 Example.Microsoft.com. All rights reserved.
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        Application info.
      </xs:appinfo>
     </xs:annotation>

  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="name"   type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="city"   type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="state"  type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="zip"    type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:NMTOKEN"
     fixed="US"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="Items">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="productName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity">
       <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
         <xs:maxExclusive value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="USPrice"    type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element ref="comment"   minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="partNum" type="SKU" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <!-- Stock Keeping Unit, a code for identifying products -->
 <xs:simpleType name="SKU">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

The Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<purchaseOrder xmlns="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" orderDate="1999-10-20">
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items>
        <item partNum="872-AA">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>
```

And the code source:

```
private static String XSD_PATH3 = "D:/work/xml_delta/test3/purshase.xsd";
    private static String XML_PATH3 = "D:/work/xml_delta/test3/purshase.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream(XSD_PATH3);
            DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = 
                    DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null, null);

            FileInputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream(XML_PATH3);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);
            traiteObject(object,"");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void traiteDynamicEntity(DynamicEntity customer,String espace)
    {
        DynamicType type = DynamicHelper.getType(customer);
        Vector<DatabaseField> list = type.getDescriptor().getAllFields();
        for(DatabaseField item : list){
            if(item.getTypeName() != null){
                int index = item.getName().indexOf("/");
                if(index != -1)
                  **// ERROR HERE**
                    System.out.println(espace+item.getName()+" : "+customer.get(item.getName().substring(0,index)));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(espace+item.getName()+" : "+customer.get(item.getName()));
                System.out.println(espace+"{");
                Object object = customer.get(item.getName());
                traiteObject(object, espace);
                System.out.println(espace+"}");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void traiteObject(Object object,String espace){
        if(object instanceof DynamicEntity)
        {
            traiteDynamicEntity((DynamicEntity)object,espace+"\t");
        }
        else if(object instanceof Collection<?>){
            for(Object item : (List<Object>)object){
                System.out.println(espace+"{");
                traiteObject(item, espace+"\t");
                System.out.println(espace+"}");
            }
        }
        else 
            if(object instanceof JAXBElement<?>){
                JAXBElement jaxbElement = (JAXBElement)object;
                System.out.println(jaxbElement);
                traiteObject(jaxbElement.getValue(), espace+"\t");
            }

    }
```

Debugging result :
[Debugging result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpdGm.png)

I really don't understand why the dynamic Entity object contains the property USPrice in lowwercase (usPrice).